# Return number of rows dependent on number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a table with this

| Id | StartDate | NoOfMonths |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | 3 |

And want a query to return this

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 |
| 2 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 |

How can I make this happen?

Comment: I don't have a clue on how to do this in a single query. Only how to solve with a while-loop or cursor, but had hoped for a solution without a loop.

Comment: As a tip you're looking for a tally table or a recursive CTE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example without an additional table:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
    ID int
    , StartDate date
    , NoOfMonths int
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '2021-09-01', 2)
,(2, '2021-09-01', 3);


WITH cte AS(
SELECT ID, StartDate, NoOfMonths
  FROM @t
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, StartDate), NoOfMonths-1
  FROM cte
  WHERE NoOfMonths > 1
)
SELECT ID, StartDate
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY ID, StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by having an additional calendar table, which would be populated and maintained by you. The content of the table could be just dates (first days of months). Then you would join records from that calendar table with your original table using `DATEADD()` function if it's MS SQL server. So something like:

```
select DateMonth
from CalendarTable ct
inner join YourTable yt 
  on ct.DateMonth between yt.StartDate and DATEADD (MONTH, yt.NoOfMonths, yt.StartDate)
```